# Network down, after upgrading debian from 10 to 11

Tags: linux, debian, linux-networking

Since I upgraded this virtual machine with Debian 10 on deck to Debian 11 and restarted, the network is down.
Tried several guided tutorials/articles, but without success.
Config from `/etc/network/interfaces` is correct.

[Terminal commands:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dlH9.png)

Before upgrade everything was working just fine.
I'm using Dedicated server with external IP address.

Main interface is `ens18` configuration `auto ens18` won't work.

There is obviously an error in my configuration. I would like to know how to configure this ens18 interface to get a static ip and get the network working again.

Comment: paste plain text directly instead using pictures. to solve the issue, read the [debian manual](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration/)

Comment: And please, report [next updates](https://serverfault.com/posts/1109354/edit) as text, not as screenshot. If you can't copy text, type it by hand. You should provide the result of `ip route`.

Comment: @djdomi Can't paste plain text, dedicated server is more than 2000km away, got only terminal via VNC...

Comment: @A.B I can't copy-paste plain text, got connection with VM only via VNC. 
Command `ip route` shows nothing.

Comment: See my answer. If it doesn't work, then you have to supply in the question the official settings asked by your ISP and a reference to its documentation. Obfuscate using values from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-3 if needed. eg: 192.0.2.0/24

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```bash
auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
  pre-up ip link set ens18 up
  address <YOUR_IP_ADDR>
  netmask <YOUR_NETMASK>
  gateway <YOUR_GATEWAY>
  up ip route del default via 137.74.x.y
  up ip route add default via 137.74.x.y
```

For more information about persistent route configurations refer to [this](https://www.mybluelinux.com/debian-permanent-static-routes/) or refer to the Debian wiki.

In most cases, the `pre-up ip link set ens18 up` is not needed but it might solve your problem.

Then restart the `networking` service:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. If You don't mind, just look on second line of image:
https://imgur.com/a/aRKCAZ7

I think I got a few tools to "Manage networks", and this can be a problem... disadvantage of constant updating/upgrading OS.

Comment: From the image, the only extra service I see is `network-manager.service`. you can stop and disable it via `sudo systemctl stop network-manager.service && sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service`, however, in the logs it says the reason for network failure is that the gateway is invalid which could be a cause of the wrong gateway address in the configuration file, are you sure the gateway address is correct?

Comment: thanks for help. Since `ip route` showed nothing (blank out), I manually typed default route with command: `ip route add default via 137.74.x.y` and it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure. You can persist this configuration by adding it to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, I have updated my answer to point this out.